# How to make a code that is run on startup execute first, before scheduled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have an application that has to do something on app's startup and only after a startup task has been completed, I want to execute the task that is defined in the function annotated with the @Scheduled. 
The current problem is that the task defined in the @Scheduled is executed before the one that is executed on startup.

I achieved the desired effect by inserting:

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```

However, I find it to be a naive solution at best, and I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution to this problem.

AppStartup.java:

```
@Component
public class AppStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        System.out.println("On startup");
    }
}
```

DataCollector.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class DataCollector {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void executeTask() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // do sth
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you use Latch and check whether the latch is open or not and perform your scheduled work?

Comment: Or simply do it from executeTask() itself (only the first time it's invoked)

Comment: @JB Nizet, yea but wouldn't it involve some kind of flag checking (for example, boolean isFirstRun)? If so, then this is not much more elegant than the solution with Thread.sleep()

Comment: Yes, it is, because it's reliable. Your sleep-based method doesn't provide any guarantee that the listener has finished executing before your task starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use a longer initialDelay?

> Number of milliseconds to delay before the first execution

like `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000, initialDelay = 10000)`

---

OR you could: register `DataCollector` as bean after you executed your initial task.

- remove `@Configuration` from DataCollector
- move `@EnableScheduling` to AppStartup
- register `DataCollector` as bean after you executed task

result:

```
@Component

public class AppStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        System.out.println("On startup");
        /* task execution */

        // register DataCollector
        applicationReadyEvent
             .getApplicationContext()
             .getBeanFactory()
             .createBean(DataCollector.class);
    }
}


public class DataCollector {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void executeTask() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // do sth
}
```

Comment: The idea with bean registry works seamlessly. Thanks :)